# .htaccess URL Rewrite Failing - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very simple rewrite rule. My entire .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

This works perfectly on one of my development machines running Apache. It does not work however on my other development machine running Apache (mod_rewrite listed in PHP info under apache2handler). Nor does it work on the live server, which I think is running Windows.

I have tried adding the following:

```
RewriteBase /
```

I'm no mod_rewrite wizard and I'm sure it's a very simple solution but it is eluding me currently and keep receiving a 404 not found error.

One thing that is different on the two environments in which this doesn't work, is that the site is not in the root of the URL. So for example it is `http://localhost/site` and `www.example.com/site`

I have tried various syntax adjustments in the .htaccess file, and also adding the site to the base:

```
RewriteBase /site
```

Comment: Try just making the rule ^.*$ for debugging

Comment: This doesn't appear to make any difference. I have also tried writing the rule explicitly. For example `ReWriteRule ^home /index.php?page=home [L,NC]
`

Comment: Also, what URL are you typing into the web browser?  You would have to type www.example.com/site/foo for this to possibly work.  You can go into your Apache logs and look for error_log to see what page exactly is 404'ing.

Comment: Yes. For example I would go to `http://localhost/site` The home page loads up correctly. If I am to go to `http://localhost/site/home` for example, it doesn't work. Yet this does work on at least one machine so the links must be set up correctly.

Comment: In the Apache ERROR LOGS I get this: `[Fri Mar 08 20:58:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/localhost/site/home
[Fri Mar 08 20:58:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/localhost/favicon.ico`

Comment: Oh, that means Apache isn't even reading your .htaccess file for this request.  Either it's in the wrong directory or mod_rewrite isn't really enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the 'RewriteBase /site' and try removing the / before index.php
The slash should't be there with use of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Does the directory http://localhost/site/home/ ALSO exists in reality? This will prevent redirecting to index.php?page=home.

Comment: `home` isn't a directory. It identifies the page, so should be rewritten to `index.php?page=home`